# Passar valores randomicos para Matriz

Tags: java, random

Tenho uma matriz com 30 valores fixos, queria saber como faço para gerar estes mesmos 30 valores, porém randômicos, se possível com limite de valores entre (2400, 400).

Como está a matriz atualmente:

```
private int[][] coordenadas = {
                { 2380, 29 },{ 2600, 59  },{ 1380, 89 },{ 780, 109},
                { 580, 139 },{ 880, 239  },{ 790, 259 },{ 760, 50 },
                { 790, 150 },{ 1980, 209 },{ 560, 45 },{ 510, 70 },
                { 930, 159 },{ 590, 80   },{ 530, 60 },{ 940, 59 },
                { 990, 30  },{ 920, 200  },{ 900, 259 },{ 660, 50 },
                { 540, 90  },{ 810, 220  },{ 900, 259 },{ 660, 50 },
                { 820, 128 },{ 490, 170  },{ 700, 30 },{ 920, 300 },
                { 856, 328 },{ 456, 320  }
        };
```

Comment: aparente cada conjunto possui um valor maior e um menor. 2400 seria o teto do maior e 400 o teto do menor pelo que entendi. 
Mas faltam outras informações, como se o primeiro valor precisa ser maior que o segundo e qual o menor valor de ambos.

Comment: 1º valor: de 500  a 2400, 2º valor: 0 a 400
Não há necessidade de que o primeiro ou o segundo sejam menores...
A ideia é que estes valores sejam onde os objetos iniciaram seus movimentos, tende ser maior de 500 para que venham de fora da tela para o lado de dentro, o segundo valor é a altura, que pode ser variável de acordo com a altura da tela (no caso, de 0 a 400)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para gerar os numeros randomicos pode-se usar as libs Math ou Random.
Prefiro, por diversos aspectos usar Random.

o método nextInt(int Limite) gera um número inteiro entre 0 e menor ou igual ao Limite. Para usar algo como [min, max] é necessário adicionar o min ao número final.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int m[][] = new int[30][2]; 
for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) { 
    m[i][0] = rand.nextInt(2400);
    m[i][1] = rand.nextInt(400);
}

// Exibindo o que foi criado
for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) { 
    System.out.printf(" {%d, %d} ", m[i][0], m[i][1]);  
}
```

[Segue o Ideone](https://ideone.com/sAcDyh)

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar a função Math.random, ela gera números aleatorios entre [0,1]

```
int m[][] = new int[30][2]; 
for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) { 
   m[i][0] = (int) Math.random()*2400; //numeros de 0 a 2400
   m[i][1] = (int) Math.random()*400; //numeros de 0 a 400
}
```

Comment: obrigado pelo edit ;)